# I don't anything about how to run javascript code

Tags: javascript

```js
function showPosition(position) {
  var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
  var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
    latlon + "&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
  document.getElementById("html.net").innerHTML = "<img src='" + img_url + "'>";
}
```

How to run this code on browser if in html file? Or if not, is there any other way to do?

Comment: Add it to an HTML file?  What are you actually asking here?

Comment: right after closing bracket "}", do this : showPosition({ coords: { lattitude: 12345, longitude: 12345 }})

Comment: Consider to learn HTML first

Comment: Guys please don't downvote right away. It looks like he is a novice in javascript and just started trying out some copied code.

Comment: There are a **number** of javascript tutorials out there. A quick search in your favourite search engine should help you accomplish this. (Examples: How do I run javascript code? | Javascript tutorials for beginners)

Comment: Why do you need to run this code? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics .

Comment: Code appears to originate from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp under "Displaying the Result in a Map".  The first section answers this question.  We would have no way of knowing this though, given that the question is entirely lacking in context.

Comment: @Amy I knew it is from somewhere... Just trying to help him in the right direction instead of downvoting :)

Comment: @binariedMe They may be a novice who's just starting out, however that doesn't excuse them from reading the _tour_ or _how to ask a question_ or _what questions are on topic_. A little research goes a _long_ way. If we allowed questions like this, we would (_and do_) have _millions_ of them.

Comment: @Amy nice find :p

Comment: @Mr.Alien Frequently with these sorts of questions, if OP had no idea how to *call* this function, it must be code they *found* somewhere.  As was the case here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put it into an HTML file and save it as `file.html` or whatever you want to name it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My First HTML Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  Check out this map
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    function showPosition(position) {
      var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
      var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
        latlon + "&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<img src='" + img_url + "'>";
    }
    //now we run the code
    showPosition({
      coords: {
        lattitude: 12345,
        longitude: 12345
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Saving the file won't run the code, neither would just opening this file in a browser.